# Access: Execute an inner join query in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, inner-join

I am trying to fill a DataGrid by an inner join query:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl1 INNER JOIN (Tbl2 INNER JOIN Tbl3 ON Tbl3.id=Tbl2.id)
ON Tbl1.id=Tbl2.id;
```

but when I try to execute the query, I get an error:

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

Is the query wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the query:

```
SELECT * FROM 

(Tbl1 INNER JOIN Tbl2 ON Tbl.id=Tbl2.id)

INNER JOIN Tbl3 ON Tbl3.id=Tbl2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect. It should be as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl1 
INNER JOIN Tbl2 ON Tbl1.id=Tbl2.id
INNER JOIN Tbl3 ON Tbl3.id=Tbl2.id
```

Comment: You are right, the syntax is incorrect because Access need parantheses to execute the inner join on multiple tables

Comment: @Remou: The table order is correct but it needs parantheses to be accepted by MS Access